# Provider variables returns null value initially

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, sqflite

Variable's value from Provider Controller returns null when the app is reloaded.

My appbar's cart icon actually shows how items are added to the cart. But when I start the app first time, it shows null as seen below[image]

But when I add a product to the cart, it shows the number of added items correctly.

Here's my code for the appbar's cart notification icon which is a text widget inside Stack.

```
 "${Provider.of<CartProvider>(context, listen: true).cart_notification}",
```

Comment: can you provider your `Provider` class code?

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/rahc20xf

Comment: My Provider class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to show `0` when app starts you just need to initial `cart_notification` like this:

```
class CartProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
// ...
  int cart_notification = 0;
// ...
}
```

but if you want to show nothing when app starts you can do it like this:

```
    final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);
    // ...
    cartProvider.cart_notification != null
        ? Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Text(
              "${cartProvider.cart_notification}",
              style: themeData.textTheme.bodyText2!.apply(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )
        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
```

**Update**:
and you have to update `cart_Notification` in `getallcart` method:

```
class CartProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
// ...
  Future<void> getallcart() async {
    cartproducts = await database.fetchall();
    cart_notification = await database.cartNotificationNumber(); // add this line
    notifyListeners();
  }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that even when there are items in my cart, the icon shows null initially when I restart my app. I want it to show the current item number.

Comment: Wait it actually worked ! Thanks ! 
I am sorry i was busy completing another project and couldn't focus on this error. But I have started working on it again after a week. I will accept your answer.
Can u please explain how it worked and where I was wrong?

Comment: You didn't initial cart_notification in provider constructor, so it was initially null

Answer (score 1):

Your cart_notification field is null initially. You should draw the badge only if the cart_notification field is not null.

Try something like:

```
Provider.of<CartProvider>(context).cart_notification != null ? Text(Provider.of<CartProvider>(context).cart_notification.toString()) : SizedBox.shrink();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. My want my cart icon to show current added item number. But the icon shows null when I restart my app even when there are multiple items added to the cart.

Comment: Provider does not save your data. It will be lost after you close the application. You should save it in some local db.